# replication slot already exists

Tags: jboss, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Whenever I restart the debezium kafka-connect container, or deploy another instance, I get the following error:

```
    io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnectionException: ERROR: replication slot "debezium" already exists
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.initReplicationSlot(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:136)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.<init>(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:79)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.<init>(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:38)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection$ReplicationConnectionBuilder.build(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:349)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresTaskContext.createReplicationConnection(PostgresTaskContext.java:80)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.RecordsStreamProducer.<init>(RecordsStreamProducer.java:75)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.start(PostgresConnectorTask.java:112)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:157)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: replication slot "debezium" already exists
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2125)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:297)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:301)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:287)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:264)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:260)
    at org.postgresql.replication.fluent.logical.LogicalCreateSlotBuilder.make(LogicalCreateSlotBuilder.java:48)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.initReplicationSlot(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:102)
    ... 14 more
```

I'm using this image: https://github.com/debezium/docker-images/tree/master/connect/0.8

And have config for it like this:

```
    {  
   "name":"record-loader-connector",
   "config":{  
      "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
      "database.dbname":"record_loader?ssl",
      "database.user":"postgres",
      "database.hostname":"redacted",
      "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"redacted",
      "database.history.kafka.topic":"dbhistory.recordloader",
      "database.password":"redacted",
      "name":"record-loader-connector",
      "database.server.name":"recordLoaderDb",
      "database.port":"20023",
      "table.whitelist":".*sync"
   },
   "tasks":[  
      {  
         "connector":"record-loader-connector",
         "task":0
      }
   ],
   "type":"source"
}
```

I've noticed these two config options (slot.name and slot.drop_on_stop), but it is not clear to me if/how I should change them:

http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/postgresql/#connector-properties

Answer (score 20):

If you deploy multiple instances of the Debezium Postgres connector, you must make sure to use distinct replication slot names. You can specify a name when setting up the connector:

```
{
    "name": "inventory-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "postgres",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "postgres",
        "database.dbname" : "postgres",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
        "database.whitelist": "inventory",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory",
        "slot.name" : "my-slot-name"
    }
}
```

I can't reproduce the issue you describe when restarting a given connector instance. It should detect that the slot already exists and re-use that one (one possible cause may be that you altered the logical decoding plug-in, too ("decoderbufs" vs. "wal2json")?. If you have a reproducer for this, could you please open an entry in our [bug tracker](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ)?

To proceed, you can manually delete the slot in Postgres:

```
select pg_drop_replication_slot('debezium');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So when I deploy a second instance of kafka-connect, it picks up the existing config that I posted, so I have no chance to specify a different value for slot name. The images run in distributed mode: https://github.com/debezium/docker-images/blob/master/connect-base/0.8/docker-entrypoint.sh#L169 and from what I can tell I assumed that meant that additional instances would coordinate.

Comment: WDYM by "pick up"? You should make sure to specify a different name, it will take the config of that JSON you're POSTing to Kafka Connect.

Comment: Also, when you say "restarting a given connector instance" do you mean from the rest api, or actually restarting the docker container itself? For me it is the latter that is causing the replication slot issues.

Comment: The former, but it also works for me when restarting the container. If you could provide exact steps for reproducing the issue, that'd be great.

Comment: re "pick up" - I docker run one kafka-connect instance, then POST the connector config. I then docker run a second kafka-connect instance, it immediately runs into the slot issue without me posting any config.

Comment: I'll create some reproducible steps, thanks for the help

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Are you running Connect in Cluster mode then? Wondering whether the issue happens during a rebalance. So yes, a reproducer would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Alas, still trying to reproduce locally with a docker-compose. I went ahead and turned on debug mode on the deployed instance that is getting the issue, and found this. Will keep digging, but figured I'd go ahead and post this:

Comment: DEBUG   No replication slot 'debezium' is present for plugin 'decoderbufs' and database 'record_loader?ssl'   [io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresConnection]
DEBUG   Creating new replication slot 'debezium' for plugin 'DECODERBUFS'   [io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection]
ERROR  ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=record-loader-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnectionException: ERROR: replication slot "debezium" already exists

Comment: And here is what is in the db:
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+--------------
slot_name           | debezium
plugin              | decoderbufs
slot_type           | logical
datoid              | 16384
database            | record_loader
temporary           | f
active              | f
active_pid          |
xmin                |
catalog_xmin        | 2223
restart_lsn         | D/9F393E98
confirmed_flush_lsn | D/9F3947F4

Comment: Ah, I logged the db was getting: 2018-06-19 18:57:34 UTC [150-654] postgres@record_loader LOG:  execute <unnamed>: select * from pg_replication_slots where slot_name = $1 and database = $2 and plugin = $3
2018-06-19 18:57:34 UTC [150-655] postgres@record_loader DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'debezium', $2 = 'record_loader?ssl', $3 = 'decoderbufs'

Comment: It is my hack to allow for ssl that is causing the issue

Comment: Not sure how to properly do ssl, I dropped ?ssl from the db name, and set database.sslmode to required, but now I get this error: {"error_code":500,"message":"Could not intialize type registry"}

Comment: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Invalid sslmode value: required

Comment: Saw this: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-238 So is require the right value to pass, and the docs just need to be updated to say that?

Comment: Yes, it's "require". We already updated the dev branch docs, will be pushed to the live website with the next release.