# Postgres debezium connector changes are not showing up under topic messages

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium, debezium-connect

I am new to Kafka and Debezium. I have succesfully created a connector for my Postgresql.

Now I have been using a sample postgres image with some inventory tables with some test data.

My registered postgres debezium connector looks as following

```
{
    "name": "inventory-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "database.hostname": "postgres",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "postgres",
        "database.dbname": "postgres",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
        "table.include.list": "inventory.customers"
    }
}
```

I have additionally created a new schema in my postgres database named 'membership' with a table named 'members' (with four columns: membership_id (bigint), firstname(name), lastname(name), created (date)).

Under my assumption that I can create a new connector for my new 'membership.member' table I have registered the following additional connector:

```
{
    "name": "membership-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "database.hostname": "postgres",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "postgres",
        "database.dbname": "postgres",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
        "table.include.list": "membership.members"
    }
}
```

Looking in my kafka ui under topics I only see the inventory topic with the snapshot and full tracking of additional inserts and updates. However my membership topic is not showing nor is anything getting CDC tracked.

Composing my enire kafka setup down and registering my membership connector first, does make it show up under my kafka topics - and also snapshots the data.
Although any further inserts are only showing changes in the identity incremental and no further data (firstname and lastname are empty). Even the created date is just a number:

```
"payload": {
        "before": null,
        "after": {
            "membership_id": 1002,
            "firstname": "", <--- why empty?
            "lastname": "", <--- why empty?
            "created": 19743
        },
        "source": {
            "version": "1.9.7.Final",
            "connector": "postgresql",
            "name": "dbserver1",
            "ts_ms": 1705835798528,
            "snapshot": "false",
            "db": "postgres",
            "sequence": "[\"37044096\",\"37044512\"]",
            "schema": "membership",
            "table": "members",
            "txId": 769,
            "lsn": 37044512,
            "xmin": null
        },
        "op": "c",
        "ts_ms": 1705835798622,
        "transaction": null
    }
```

So my question is why I am not seeing all my data in my payload for membership inserts?

I am not sure what triggered it. But it is working now (the snapshot on membership). I suppose creating a topic and registering my connector can take some time?

Although - now I have done additional inserts in my membership table, and still waiting for my kafka topic to intercept the CDC from postgres. The change messages are not yet showing :(
Inserting in the inventory.customers tables are working and showing up:

[image]

Still waiting for my membership changes to show up here:

[image]

Comment: Anything to do with replication slot in Postgres?
I am seeing this in the log:
ERROR:  replication slot "debezium" is active for PID 80

Comment: Found an error in the log file:
ERROR  Postgres|dbserver1|streaming  Producer failure   [io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler]
2024-01-21 14:47:32 io.debezium.DebeziumException: Failed to start replication stream at LSN{0/23EBA68}; when setting up multiple connectors for the same database host, please make sure to use a distinct replication slot name for each.
2024-01-21 14:47:32 at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.startStreaming(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:329)

Comment: Use  distinct slot name:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746419/replication-slot-already-exists

Comment: That helped and now CDC is working for both connectors. 
My 2nd connector takes a while to be registered and looking into my debezium log I notice many attempts:
'Unable to register metrics as an old set with the same name exists, retrying in PT5S (attempt 3 out of 12)   [io.debezium.metrics.Metrics]'  which it tries 12 times and an additional 2nd run for 12 times again. This is why my 2nd topic takes more than two minutes to get registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slotname must be configured additionally in the connector json:

Example:

```
{
    "name": "inventory-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "postgres",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "postgres",
        "database.dbname" : "postgres",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
        "database.whitelist": "inventory",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory",
        "slot.name" : "my_slot_name01"
    }
}
```

If your 'before' in kafka messages is null after updates. You have to fix your replica identity of your table:

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.mytable REPLICA IDENTITY FULL;
```

Comment: Timestamp is in epoch unix format: https://www.epochconverter.com/